# Is my 802.11ax wireless card a counterfeit?

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, pcie

I've recently bought a miniPCIe wireless adapter that claims to contain an Intel chipset that supports 802.11ax (Wi-Fi 6). It's not made by Intel, but claims to contain the same chipset as their AX200 wireless cards.

The card works, but the output of the `iw list` command has me suspecting that I've received a counterfeit card containing an older 802.11ac chipset. Namely, the output does not contain any mention of 'HE capabilities' (802.11ax), like in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186306/wifi-iw-setting-bit-rate) question, only HT (802.11n) and VHT (802.11ac). It also does not list CCMP-256 among supported ciphers, which it should according to Intel's specification.

I'm running kernel 5.3. Is there any chance this is the fault of an outdated driver or something similar?

Edit: I'm running Linux Mint 19.3, which is based on Ubuntu 18.04
`iw` itself that's available there (5.4 vs  4.14 on 18.04) that made the difference. I guess this answers my question.
Output of diagnostic commands:

```
#lspci -s 02:00.0
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
#lshw -c network
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 34:13:e8:c2:bd:70
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-51-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.88.250 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7c03fff
#iw list
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 20
    max scan IEs length: 365 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 20
    max # match sets: 11
    max # scan plans: 2
    max scan plan interval: 65535
    max scan plan iterations: 254
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    Device supports AP-side u-APSD.
    Device supports T-DLS.
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * GCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:8)
        * GCMP-256 (00-0f-ac:9)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
        * GMAC-128 (00-0f-ac:11)
        * GMAC-256 (00-0f-ac:12)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x19ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (22.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
    Band 2:
        Capabilities: 0x19ef
            RX LDPC
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            TX STBC
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
        HT Max RX data rate: 300 Mbps
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15
        VHT Capabilities (0x039071f6):
            Max MPDU length: 11454
            Supported Channel Width: 160 MHz
            RX LDPC
            short GI (80 MHz)
            short GI (160/80+80 MHz)
            TX STBC
            SU Beamformee
            MU Beamformee
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: not supported
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 0 Mbps
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5180 MHz [36] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5340 MHz [68] (disabled)
            * 5360 MHz [72] (disabled)
            * 5380 MHz [76] (disabled)
            * 5400 MHz [80] (disabled)
            * 5420 MHz [84] (disabled)
            * 5440 MHz [88] (disabled)
            * 5460 MHz [92] (disabled)
            * 5480 MHz [96] (disabled)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5720 MHz [144] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
            * 5865 MHz [173] (disabled)
            * 5885 MHz [177] (disabled)
            * 5905 MHz [181] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * tdls_mgmt
         * tdls_oper
         * start_sched_scan
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * connect
         * disconnect
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * add_tx_ts
         * set_multicast_to_unicast
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on disconnect
         * wake up on magic packet
         * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes,
           maximum packet offset 0 bytes
         * can do GTK rekeying
         * wake up on GTK rekey failure
         * wake up on EAP identity request
         * wake up on 4-way handshake
         * wake up on rfkill release
         * wake up on network detection, up to 11 match sets
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    P2P GO supports CT window setting
    P2P GO supports opportunistic powersave setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device adds DS IE to probe requests
    Device can update TPC Report IE
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports dynamic SMPS
    Device supports WMM-AC admission (TSPECs)
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports VHT-IBSS.
```

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having booted up a live image of Ubuntu 20.04, I did get an output containing HE capabilities section, though curiously I still didn't see CCMP-256 cipher support. I'm guessing it's the newer version of `iw` itself (5.4 vs 4.15 on 18.04) that makes the difference.

Thanks to K7AAY for the implied suggestion to try a different OS.